# cocos2d-js: b2DebugDraw can't be initialized. element.getContext("2d") returns null

Tags: cocos2d-x, getelementbyid, cocos2d-js

I tried to use b2DebugDraw and I couldn't initialize it, because I get a null returned from getContext function. I know that this is not a cocos2d element, but it works fine in other contexts.

I created a new empty hello world project with "cocos new -l js", and placed following code at the end of the ctor function of the HelloWorldLayer:

```
var b2Vec2 = Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2,
    b2World = Box2D.Dynamics.b2World,
    b2DebugDraw = Box2D.Dynamics.b2DebugDraw;

this.world = new b2World(new b2Vec2(0, -5), true);

var debugDraw = new b2DebugDraw();
var element = document.getElementById("gameCanvas"),
    context = element.getContext("2d");   // context is null so
debugDraw.SetSprite(context);             // sprite is not set
debugDraw.SetDrawScale(20.0);
debugDraw.SetFillAlpha(0.5);
debugDraw.SetLineThickness(1.0);          // and crashes in SetLineThickness
```

What is wrong?

Engine version is 3.0a2

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to pass from using box2d + ease.js to cocos2d v3.0 with box2d and it is giving me the same troubles;

I finally solved adding a more canvas to the main "gameCanvas" (i put it before it in my index.html) and calling it in my b2DebugDraw method in place of the cocos2d related one:

```
draw:function (ctx) {

         this.world.DrawDebugData();
         this._super(ctx);

    },

debugDraw: function(){
    var myDebugDraw = new b2DebugDraw();

    myDebugDraw.SetSprite(document.getElementById("debug").getContext("2d"));
    //debug instead of gameCanvas

    myDebugDraw.SetDrawScale(scale);
    myDebugDraw.SetFillAlpha(0.8);
    myDebugDraw.SetLineThickness(1.0); // no need to change this anymore
    myDebugDraw.SetFlags(b2DebugDraw.e_shapeBit | b2DebugDraw.e_jointBit);
    this.world.SetDebugDraw(myDebugDraw);



}
```

nothing more than this. No need either to change the SetLineThickness, the error was probably related to the null context.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, brother. You did a great job.